# Why does executing SparkR jobs give Permission denied using Oozie?

Tags: shell, hadoop, apache-spark, oozie, sparkr

I am running sparkr through shell script with oozie. When i run the job i am facing permission issue:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=yarn, access=WRITE, inode="/user":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread delete Spark local dirs
java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "delete Spark local dirs" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

the overall log..

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/mntc/yarn/nm/filecache/2452/sparkr-  assembly-0.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
15/09/08 01:39:11 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.3.0
15/09/08 01:39:13 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: yarn
15/09/08 01:39:13 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: yarn
15/09/08 01:39:13 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication 
disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(yarn); users with modify permissions: Set(yarn)
15/09/08 01:39:13 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/09/08 01:39:13 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/09/08 01:39:14 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :  
  /mnt/yarn/nm/usercache/karun/appcache
  /application_1437539731669_0786/blockmgr-1760ec19-b1de-4bcc-9100- b2c1364b54c8 
  /mntc/yarn/nm/usercache/karun/appcache/application_1437539731669_0786/    
   blockmgr-f57c89eb-4a4b-4fd5-9796-ca3c3a7f2c6f
 15/09/08 01:39:14 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at     
  15/09/08 01:39:14 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 265.4 MB
  15/09/08 01:39:15 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
    15/09/08 01:39:16 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (6610 MB per container)
    15/09/08 01:39:16 INFO Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
    createSparkContext on edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.RRDD failed with  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=yarn, access=WRITE, inode="/user":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
  Exception in thread "delete Spark local dirs" java.lang.NullPointerException
  Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
```

i dont know how to resolve this issue.any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be because you don't have such user "yarn" in HDFS. There's two possible solutions.

1. Create such user on HDFS and grant him an access to resources it needs.
2. Simpler, just execute your job under hdfs user(or what ever you have on hdfs). Set user.name=hdfs in oozie property file. [ozie doc](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/AG_Install.html#Oozie_User_Authentication_Configuration)